# Variable lifetime qs in function

Tags: rust, lifetime

```
fn get_str1<'a>() -> &'a str {
    let x = "hello";
    return x;
}

fn get_str2<'a>(str1: &str) -> &'a str {
    let x: &'a str = (str1.to_string() + "123").as_str();
    return x;
}

fn get_str3<'a>(str1: &str) -> &'a str {
    let tmp = str1.to_string() + "123";
    let x: &'a str = tmp.as_str();
    return x;
}

#[test]
fn lifetime_test() {
    println!("{}", get_str1());
    println!("{}", get_str2("hello"));
    println!("{}", get_str3("hello"))
}
```

When I call `get_str1`, it has no problem, but when I call `get_str2`, it has a compilation error:

```
error[E0597]: borrowed value does not live long enough
 --> src/main.rs:7:22
  |
7 |     let x: &'a str = (str1.to_string() + "123").as_str();
  |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^         - temporary value only lives until here
  |                      |
  |                      temporary value does not live long enough
  |
note: borrowed value must be valid for the lifetime 'a as defined on the function body at 6:1...
 --> src/main.rs:6:1
  |
6 | fn get_str2<'a>(str1: &str) -> &'a str {
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  = note: consider using a `let` binding to increase its lifetime
```

When I call `get_str3`, it also has a compilation error:

```
error[E0597]: `tmp` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:13:22
   |
13 |     let x: &'a str = tmp.as_str();
   |                      ^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
14 |     return x;
15 | }
   | - borrowed value only lives until here
   |
note: borrowed value must be valid for the lifetime 'a as defined on the function body at 11:1...
  --> src/main.rs:11:1
   |
11 | fn get_str3<'a>(str1: &str) -> &'a str {
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Why do I get these errors and how do I fix `get_str2` and `get_str3`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first function works because the string has the `'static` lifetime and will be promoted by the compiler.

As for the others..

```
fn get_str2<'a>(str1: &str) -> &'a str {
    let x = (str1.to_string() + "123").as_str();
    return x
}
```

This part: `str1.to_string()`, isn't returning a string slice... but a new instance of a `String`. This is basically the same as this:

```
let x = str1.to_string(); // this is of type String, and its lifetime is local to this function
let y = str1 + "123"; // This consumes str1 and appends a &str to it - thus the lifetime is still of the new String instance above
let z = y.as_str(); // This returns a reference to the local String instance
```

Reading each comment above, it becomes clear that you're actually trying to return a reference to a local `String`. You can't do this, because the `String` will be destroyed at the end of the function and the reference will be invalid.

This applies to your third function as well. You're returning a reference to a `String` instance that will be destroyed at the end of the function.